# ¿Cómo combino un archivo de audio mp3 con múltiples videos mp4 con ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Necesito combinar un solo archivo de música mp3, por ejemplo shakira.mp3, con "n" multiples archivos de video mp4 con ffmpeg. Como resultado de utilizar el código debo obtener la misma cantidad de videos "n", con la canción shakira.mp3 agregada a todos ellos.

Encontré un código que permite confinar un archivo de audio con un solo video, pero por cuestiones de ahorrar tiempo necesito que lo haga con varios videos:

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i song.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest output\video.mp4

Comment: Hola Charlie, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Sería útil que menciones el sistema operativo o la terminal que estás usando. Tal vez ffmpeg no tenga una forma integrada de hacerlo y tengas que recurrir a funciones de la terminal.

Comment: Hola Mateo. Estoy usando Windows 10 cómo sistema operativo.